# Adding lists to a new list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I did not get this question right. The function `read_words` turns a text file with a bunch of names in new lines into a list and it works.

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str
    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.
    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """
    words_list = []
    words = words_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        new_word = words[i]
        for char in '\n':
            new_word = new_word.replace(char,'')
            words_list.append(new_word)
    return words_list
```

the problem arises when I try to get a list of lists

```
def read_board(board_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of list of str
    Return a board read from open file board_file. The board file will contain
    one row of the board per line. Newlines are not included in the board.
    """
    board_list = []
    row_list = []
    rows = read_words(board_file)
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        for  char in rows[i]:
            row_list.append(char)
        board_list.append(row_list)
    return board_list
```

the goal is to turn a text file of the type:

```
ABCD
EFGH
```

into `[['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H']]`

I have already tried playing around with the indices for `board_list.append(row_list)` call without luck. How can I get this to work?

Comment: `[list(line) for line in file]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) like:

#### Code:

```
def read_board(board_file):
    return [list(line.strip()) for line in read_words(board_file)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str
    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.
    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """
    return [word.strip() for word in words_file.readlines()]

def read_board(board_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of list of str
    Return a board read from open file board_file. The board file will contain
    one row of the board per line. Newlines are not included in the board.
    """
    return [list(line) for line in read_words(board_file)]

with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    board = read_board(f)

print(board)
```

#### Results:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]
```

Comment: If you strip the lines in `read_words`, why do you strip them again in `read_board`?

Comment: its... beautiful. Also i didn't know you could call return and for loop in the same line. I'm a changed man.

Comment: @GuriqbalChouhan List comprehension will definitely change the way you look at code.